# Google form: separate survey answers and respondent's contact info

Tags: forms, google-sheets, survey

I would like to make a survey and to get people to answer I'll offer a prize. I need to separate the answers of the survey and the respondent's contact info, so that the survey may be answered anonymous.

I thought about coding the whole thing myself in php, but thought it would be easier to use Google form. Is either of these options possible in Google form:

1. Collect all the survey answers into one spreadsheet, and the contact data (separate questions on the last form page) into another?
2. Collect the form answers into a spreadsheet as normal and on the "thank-you-note" in the end, direct the respondent to another spreadsheet? I can't figure out how to place an url-link in google forms. Is it possible?
3. Have an e-mail-link on the "thank-you-note", telling them to send me an e-mail in order to get the prize?

Thank you for any tips or answers you may offer me :-)

(P.s. I tried to tag my question google-form, but that tag was not available.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 cannot be done -- all the form responses are saved on the same sheet.

Option 2 is easy -- while editing the form, choose More actions > Edit confirmation and enter something like "Your response has been recorded. Visit http://www.example.com/ to enter the lottery." The URL will be clickable in the confirmation dialog box. Links can also be put in the lead paragraph of the form -- it is the multi-line text box right after the heading field of the form.

Option 3 ditto.

You may also want to take a look at Bryan's FORMS+ template (https://plus.google.com/u/2/107003645867482308046/about).

Cheers --Hyde

Answer (score 0):

I know, this thread isn't the newest one, but it describes my problem too.

The question is, as i offer at the Thank You Box a link to a new form, the new spreadsheet will collect the name with a new timestamp, which isn't very far away from the "anonymous" data, which makes it definitely not anonymous...

Is there a way to filter or skip the timestamp in the survey?

Comment: Kindly consider posting this as comment and not as answer, Work your way to get the privileges.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new and actually i was looking for such thing like a comment, but my screen was so bright that i didn't see the bright grey comment link in first place, kind regards ;-)